# Set constraint mip

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint

I am programming a MIP problem. There are two continuous variables but only one can have a value and the other must then be zero.
How do I give this as a constraint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ denote your continuous variables. Introduce binary variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ and impose the following constraints:

- $x_1 > 0 \; \Longrightarrow \; y_1 = 1$:
  $$
  x_1 \le My_1
  $$
- $x_2 > 0 \; \Longrightarrow \; y_2 = 1$:
  $$
  x_2 \le My_2
  $$
- $y_1$ and $y_2$ cannot be active simultaneously:
  $$
  y_1 +y_2 \le 1
  $$

$M$ is an upper bound on your variables. If you have different upper bounds for $x_1$ and $y_2$, use two different values of $M$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Now it works like a charm

Comment: *"M is an upper bound on your variables. If you have different upper bounds for x1 and y2, use two different values of M"* This sentence is not necessary. If M1 is an upper bound on x1 and M2 is an upper bound on x2, then M = max(M1,M2) is an upper bound on both x1 and x2.

Comment: True, but for numerical purposes, it is better to have the tighest bound possible for each constraint.

Answer (score 3):

With many MIP solvers, you can use SOS constraints. (SOS Type 1 is a set of variables where at most one variable may be nonzero.)

SOS1 [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoosos1.py) with cplex docplex python api:
from docplex.mp.model import Model

```
mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print("and with SOS1")

mdl.add_sos1([nbbus40,nbbus30])

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Or you can also write your SOS1 with logical constraints. For [instance, in OPL](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosos1.mod)

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
 
 // SOS1
 (nbBus40>=1)+(nbBus30>=1)<=1;
}
```